# Activate radio buttons using checkbox conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Basically i'd like to activate radio buttons using a checkbox as per the conditions given below-

1. If i check the checkbox, the first radio would be checked. If i change to another radio button, the checkbox still checked.
2. If i uncheck the checkbox, I would like to uncheck any radio button. I mean, the radio buttons need to be checked if the checkbox is checked, and if the checkbox is unchecked, the radio buttons need to be unchecked as well.

I've tried a bunch of partial solutions, but none of them work correctly. :(

My HTML:

```
<input name="featured_ad" value="1" type="checkbox">condition
<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497649">value 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497648">value 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497647">value 3<br>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Once an option is chosen from a radio group, you cannot reliably remove it. If you need this behaviour, you would be better to have the radio buttons disabled by default and then enable/disable them based on the state of the checkbox. Alternatively you could remove the checkbox and add a fourth radio for 'Not required'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using pure javascript.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3bugg14y/1/

HTML:

```
<input name="featured_ad" value="1" type="checkbox" onclick="resetradio(this)">condition
<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497649" onclick="setcheckbox()">value 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497648" onclick="setcheckbox()">value 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497647" onclick="setcheckbox()">value 3<br>
```

JS:

```
function resetradio (checkbox) {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('ad_pack_id');
    var index = 0, length = radios.length;
    if (checkbox.checked == false) {
        for ( ; index < length; index++) {
            radios[index].checked = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        radios[index].checked = true;
    }
}

function setcheckbox () {
    var checkbox = document.getElementsByName('featured_ad')[0];
    if (checkbox.checked == false) {
        checkbox.checked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @JacquesMarais oops sorry didn't realize that was requirement. Updated answer. I didn't change html other than to add on clicks but I would recommend giving the checkbox an id.

Comment: This is the best solution because it is pure JavaScript and actually works.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `removeProp()` to unselect radio button and `prop()` to select checkbox.

```js
$(function(){
  $('input[name=featured_ad]').change(function(){
     if(!$(this).is(":checked"))
       $("input[name=ad_pack_id]").removeProp("checked");
     else
        $("input[name=ad_pack_id]:first").prop("checked",true);
  });

  $('input[name=ad_pack_id]').click(function(){
      $('input[name=featured_ad]').prop("checked",true); 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="featured_ad" value="1" type="checkbox">condition
<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497649">value 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497648">value 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497647">value 3<br>
```

Comment: This doesn't select the first value if you check the checkbox.

Comment: @JacquesMarais, yes i forgot to mention that. Please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, You can do something like this:

```js
$(':checkbox').on("click", function(event) {
  if (this.checked)
    $(':radio:first').prop('checked', this.checked);
  else
    $(':radio').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="featured_ad" value="1">condition
<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497649">value 1
<br>
<input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497648">value 2
<br>
<input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497647">value 3
<br>
```

Comment: This works, but doesn't check the checkbox if a radio is selected.

Comment: @JacquesMarais That is not mentioned in the problem description... It does what the OP asked for in question... nothing more

Comment: He wants what the @JacquesMarais suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Check below snippet

```
function set(event){
    if(event.checked=== false && event.type === "checkbox"){
       var ele = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']");
       for(var i = 0; i<ele.length; i++)
       {
          ele[i].checked = false;
       }
     }
    else if(event.checked=== true && event.type === "checkbox"){
        var ele = document.querySelector("input[type='radio']");
        if(ele){
            ele.checked = true;
        }
    }
   else if (event.type !== "checkbox")
   {
     var ele = document.querySelector("input[type='checkbox']");
     if(ele){
        ele.checked = true;
     }
    }
}
```

changes in html:

```
<input name="featured_ad" value="1" type="checkbox" onClick="set(this)">condition
<br><br>
<input type="radio" class="a" name="ad_pack_id" value="497649" onClick="set(this)">value 1<br>
<input type="radio" class="a" name="ad_pack_id" value="497648" onClick="set(this)">value 2<br>
<input type="radio" class="a" name="ad_pack_id" value="497647" onClick="set(this)">value 3<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Added a property to hide/show the radio buttons based on the checkbox condition.**

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3bugg14y/3/

HTML:

```
<input name="featured_ad" value="1" type="checkbox" onclick="resetradio(this)">condition
<br><br>
<div id="buttons" style="display:none">
<input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497649">value 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497648">value 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497647">value 3<br>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function resetradio (checkbox)
{
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('ad_pack_id');
    var index = 0, length = radios.length;
    if (checkbox.checked == false)
    {
        document.getElementById('buttons').style.display='none';
        for ( ; index < length; index++)
        {
            radios[index].checked = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('buttons').style.display='block';
        radios[index].checked = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Also keeping track of the last selected radio button, after unchecking the checkbox.

```js
var check = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]'),
    radioBtns = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')),
    isRadioChecked = false,
    lastCheckedRadio = 0;


check.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.checked) {
    radioBtns.forEach(function(elem) {
      elem.checked = false;
    });
    isRadioChecked = false;
  } else {
    if (!isRadioChecked) {
      radioBtns[lastCheckedRadio].checked = true;
    }
  }
}, false);

radioBtns.forEach(function(elem, index) {
  elem.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      isRadioChecked = true;
      lastCheckedRadio = index;
    } else {
      isRadioChecked = false;
    }
    if (e.target.checked && !check.checked) {
      check.checked = true;
    }
  }, false);
});
```

```html
<input name="featured_ad" value="1" type="checkbox">condition
<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497649">value 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497648">value 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497647">value 3<br>
```