# Hide and Show radio buttons with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Basically i'd like hide and show the radio buttons if the checkbox is checked or not, but with some conditions.

1. The first radio button needs to be checked by default even if hidden once the checkbox has been checked.
2. If the checkbox has been checked then show all the radio buttons and the user can choose another radio button if necessary.
3. But, if the checkbox is unchecked, set the radio button back to the first checked by default and hide all the radio buttons.

I tried to modify some solutions that i found, but without success :(

My HTML:

```
<input name="featured_ad" value="1" type="checkbox">condition</input>
<div class="buttons">
    <input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497649">value 1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497648">value 2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497647">value 3<br>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please show the Javascript that you tried.

Comment: This question looks very similar to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33215234/activate-radio-buttons-using-checkbox-conditions/33215441#33215441 What was the problem with accepted solution?

Comment: @AtheistP3ace has been a change of plans and i need to keep the first radio button checked even the checkbox was unchecked, but i dont known how to modify your code to do this. Can you modify?

Comment: Sure, so to clarify. Does first radio still get checked when you check checkbox?

Comment: Yes! And if i change for other radio after the checkbox was checked, when uncheck the checkbox, the radio return to the first, because is the default.

Comment: @EderAugusto Added answer below. Let me know if thats what you want. If not I will modify after you tell what I may have missed in your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed does this work for you?

HTML:

```
<input name="featured_ad" value="1" type="checkbox" onclick="resetradio(this)">condition
<div class="buttons">
    <input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497649" onclick="setcheckbox()">value 1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497648" onclick="setcheckbox()">value 2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497647" onclick="setcheckbox()">value 3<br>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function resetradio (checkbox) {
    var buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('ad_pack_id');
    radios[0].checked = true;
    if (checkbox.checked == true) {
        buttons.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        buttons.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

function setcheckbox () {
    var checkbox = document.getElementsByName('featured_ad')[0];
    if (checkbox.checked == false) {
        checkbox.checked = true;
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.buttons {
    display: none;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dgqn5fc4/1/

Comment: This works better to me, its perfect, i just need to hide the div "buttons" and show if the checkbox is checked

Comment: I'll update, so if checkbox is not checked hide the buttons div, and when checkbox is checked show it?

Comment: @EderAugusto updated answer and fiddle to hide and show div based on checkbox.

Comment: That's it. Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: can you help me one more time to improve your code? I did a modification here https://jsfiddle.net/dgqn5fc4/2/ but doesn't work how i wish. I need add a second checkbox who works like a radio button with the old one. And, when a check the new box, hide a div "buttons" if is open.

Comment: Sure! So what does new checkbox do? Sorry I am a bit confused what you want.

Comment: The new checkbox is checked by default, it is a featured for a client who choose between the first and the second checkbox. If the second is choose, then, show the radio buttons. If he backs to the first, hide the buttons. And, if he unchecked both, hide the radio buttons too.

The function to reset the radio buttons is fine, perfect, i just need to add this second checkbox to the behavior.

Comment: @EderAugusto ok I understand. Just left work. I'll update fiddle tonight for you.

Comment: So I guess I am still a bit confused. These checkboxes work some what like a radio button? Only one can be checked at once? And to start the second one is checked and the radio buttons are showing, if they check first checkbox the second is unchecked and the first radio button is checked and radio buttons are hidden. if they check second checkbox the first is unchecked and the radio buttons are shown. if they uncheck both radio buttons are hidden and the first radio is checked by default too?

Comment: Yes, only one checkbox can be checked at once. No, to start the first checkbox is checked and the radio buttons is hidden (but the first radio button need to be checked, always, hiden or shown). If the user check the second checkbox, so, show the radio buttons. If the user back to the first checkbox, hide the radio buttons and reset they (i mean, the first radio back to be checked).

Comment: Thats it! Thanks a lot, you save my project.

Comment: @EderAugusto no problem!

Comment: @AtheistP3ace hi i need some help T_T what if checkbox is true then i will show the amount with value of zero else false i will hide the amount of zero note value is in the example td ng-repeat="value in balance " balance= [ 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 0, 0]

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few issues here. First of all, you need to make sure you close your input tags:

```
<input name="featured_ad" value="1" type="checkbox">condition</input>

<div class="buttons">
    <input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497649">value 1</input>
    <input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497648">value 2</input>
    <input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497647">value 3</input>
</div>
```

You can then check your default radio button right in the html by adding checked="checked" to the appropriate radio element.

```
<div class="buttons">
    <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="ad_pack_id" value="497649">value 1</input>
    <input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497648">value 2</input>
    <input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497647">value 3</input>
</div>
```

You can hide your radio buttons by default in your CSS:

```
.buttons {
    display: none; 
}
```

Then, you can show them using jQuery, and do your selections based on your condition:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='featured_ad']").on("change", function(){
        var isChecked = $(this).prop("checked"); 
        if(isChecked){
            $(".buttons").show(); 
        } else {
            $(".buttons").hide(); 
            $("input[name='ad_pack_id'][value='497649']").prop("checked", "checked"); 
        }
    }); 
});
```

**Edit:**

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8q94Lvbo/

Answer (score 0):

Do the following.

```js
$('[name="featured_ad"]').on('change', function(){
  var $first = $('[name="ad_pack_id"]').first();
  var $rest = $('[name="ad_pack_id"]').slice(1);
  if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
    $first.prop('checked',true);
    $first
      .closest('span')
      .hide();
    $rest.prop({
      'checked':false,
      'disabled':false
    });
    
  } else {
    $first
      .closest('span')
      .show();
    $first.prop('checked',true);
    $rest.prop({
      'checked':false,
      'disabled':true
    });
  }
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="featured_ad" value="1" type="checkbox">condition
<div class="buttons">
    <span><input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497649">value 1</span><br/>
    <span><input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497648">value 2</span><br/>
    <span><input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" value="497647">value 3</span><br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass arguments to javaScript in quotes like **onclick="Show_Div('Div_1')"** not like **onclick="Show_Div(Div_1)"**.

And for others requirement you can check the following html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" onclick="checkFun();"/>Your CheckBox<br/>
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/flower-icon.png" alt="" onclick="Show_Div('Div_1')" width="100px">
    <p>
      <input id="radio1" type="radio" onclick="Show_Div('Div_1')" class="cb1" onchange="cbChange1(this)" checked="checked"/>Flower 1</p>
    <div id="Div_1" style="display: none;">
      Flower is pink.
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/d/w/v/V/p/pink-flower-md.png" alt="" onclick="Show_Div('Div_2')" width="100px">
    <p>
      <input type="radio" id="radio2" onclick="Show_Div('Div_2')" class="cb1" onchange="cbChange1(this)" disabled >Flower 2</p>
    <div id="Div_2" style="display: none;">
      Flower is orange.
</div>
```

You can apply following simple JS and jQuery to achive your goal

```
function checkFun(){
  console.log("click");
  var ch=$("#check");
  if(ch.is(':checked')){
    $("#radio2").attr("disabled",false);
  }else{
   $("#radio1").prop("checked", true);
    $("#radio2").prop("checked", false);
    $("#radio2").attr("disabled",true);
  }
}
function Show_Div(Div_id) {
  if(Div_id=="Div_1"){

    $("#Div_1").show();
    $("#Div_2").hide();
  }else{
    $("#Div_2").show();
    $("#Div_1").hide();
  }
}
    function cbChange1(obj) {
        var cb1 = document.getElementsByClassName("cb1");
        for (var i = 0; i < cb1.length; i++) {
            cb1[i].checked = false;
        }
        obj.checked = true;
    }
```